# can we implement functionality like iBooks in our own app?

Tags: ios

whenever we sync pdf files. it shows in our app.

because I want upload that pdf file on server.
but I couldn't find any other way to do that.
I have tried to access pdf from iBooks but there is no way to access other app file in our app.

so is their any way to do that?
appreciate for help

Answer (score 1):

You can upload the PDF to your server and show a webview where you load the URL for your PDF file